# How to update Firestore field called `likes`. I wanna plus or minus one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question about how to update a number field in Cloud Firestore. I followed an official document and it was not that hard to write code. But it didn't work as I wanted.
It seems like I didn't use async and await properly. I haven't perfectly understood async and await now, so no idea where I missed.

## GoodBad.jsx

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { FaHeart, FaRegHeart } from 'react-icons/fa';
// import { FaThumbsUp, FaRegThumbsUp } from "react-icons/fa";
import {updateDoc, getDoc, doc } from 'firebase/firestore';

import db from '../config/firebase';

const GoodBad = ({ quiz }) => {
  const [goodClicked, setGoodClicked] = useState(false);
  const [goodCounter, setGoodCounter] = useState(quiz.likes);

  // console.log(quiz.id, quiz.likes)

  const handleLikesUI = async (e) => {
    if (goodClicked === false) {
      setGoodClicked(true);
      setGoodCounter(prevState => prevState + 1);
    } else {
      setGoodClicked(false);
      setGoodCounter(prevState => prevState - 1);
    }

    const docRef = doc(db, "quizzes", quiz.id)
    const payload = {likes: goodCounter}
    await updateDoc(docRef, payload);
  };


  return (
    <div className='quizFooter'>
      <div
        className={
          goodClicked
            ? 'likesCounterContainer checked'
            : 'likesCounterContainer'
        }
        onClick={() => handleLikesUI(quiz)}
      >
        <span className='heartIcon'>
          {goodClicked ? <FaHeart /> : <FaRegHeart />}{' '}
        </span>
        <span className='likesNumber'>{goodCounter}</span>
        {/* <span onClick={handleDislikes}>{goodClicked ? <FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-regular fa-thumbs-down" /> : <FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-solid fa-thumbs-down" />}bad: {badCounter}, {badClicked}</span> */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default GoodBad;
```

Comment: there is a better [way](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?authuser=0#increment_a_numeric_value) to increment numeric values in firestore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using `useEffect()` for your use-case.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const payload = {likes: goodCounter}
    updateDoc(docRef, payload)
  }, [goodCounter]);

  const handleLikesUI = async (e) => {
    if (goodClicked === false) {
      setGoodClicked(true);
      setGoodCounter(prevState => prevState + 1);
    } else {
      setGoodClicked(false);
      setGoodCounter(prevState => prevState - 1);
    }
  };
```

On the code above, this will listen to changes of `goodCounter` in realtime and if there's change on the value of `goodCounter`, it will now proceed updating your document. If you wont use useEffect, there will be a delay when setting `setGoodCounter`.

As @mocherfaoui stated, if you want to just increment(or decrement) the existing value of a field, you must use `increment`. See sample code below:

```
if (goodClicked) {
   const n = 1
} else {
   const n = -1
}

updateDoc(docRef, {
    // `n` would be the number of increments (1 or -1).
    likes: increment(n)
});
```

For more information, you may check this [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects).